# How can I resize and upload an image for the amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: php, exif, php-gd

I am trying to resize an image with `imagecopyresampled()` and at the same time remove the EXIF data from the image with `imagecreatefromjpeg()` before uploading to S3.  I am not sure what I am missing, because the image uploads but doesn't resize.

```
$fileToUpload = 'file';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["$fileToUpload"]['tmp_name'];
$file_name        = ($_FILES["$fileToUpload"]["name"]);

        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_name);
        list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($tmp_name);
        $width = 50; //px
        $height = 50; //px
        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); // resize image
        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);//changes original image


                $config = [
                    's3-access' => [
                        'key' => 'awsAccessKey',
                        'secret' => 'awsSecretKey',
                        'bucket' => 'awsBucket',
                        'region' => 'us-east-1', 
                        'version' => 'latest',
                        'acl' => 'public-read',
                        'private-acl' => 'private'
                    ]
                ];     //# initializing s3
                $s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory([
                    'credentials' => [
                        'key' => $config['s3-access']['key'],
                        'secret' => $config['s3-access']['secret']
                    ],
                    'version' => $config['s3-access']['version'],
                    'region' => $config['s3-access']['region']
                ]);
                $request_status = $s3->putObject([
                    'Bucket' => $config['s3-access']['bucket'],
                    'Key' => $file_name,
                    'SourceFile' => $tmp_name,
                    'ACL' => $config['s3-access']['acl']
                ]);
```

Comment: So your only problem is removing the EXIF data? You can surely make this question more simple by removing the rest of the code. S3 has nothing to do with this problem. See info on how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I wanted to remove EXIF and upload the file to S3 which makes it more complicated.

Comment: But you said "the image uploads" therefore this isn't part of the problem.

Comment: That's what's bugging me.  It takes the original temp file and uploads it, but didn't modify it in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pulling the image out and running `imagecopyresampled` on it, but you never write the new image to disk, and just upload the original file.

Try this:

```
$fileToUpload = 'file';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["$fileToUpload"]['tmp_name'];
$file_name = $_FILES["$fileToUpload"]["name"];

list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($tmp_name);
$width = 50;
$height = 50;
// get the old image from disk
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp_name);
// create a new image
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
// resample the old image into the new image
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
// clean up
imagedestroy($src);
// save the new image to disk
imagejpeg($image_p, $tmp_name);
// clean up
imagedestroy($image_p);

$config = [
    's3-access' => [
        'key' => 'awsAccessKey',
        'secret' => 'awsSecretKey',
        'bucket' => 'awsBucket',
        'region' => 'us-east-1', 
        'version' => 'latest',
        'acl' => 'public-read',
        'private-acl' => 'private',
    ]
];

$s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory([
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => $config['s3-access']['key'],
        'secret' => $config['s3-access']['secret'],
    ],
    'version' => $config['s3-access']['version'],
    'region' => $config['s3-access']['region'],
]);

$request_status = $s3->putObject([
    'Bucket' => $config['s3-access']['bucket'],
    'Key' => $file_name,
    'SourceFile' => $tmp_name,
    'ACL' => $config['s3-access']['acl'],
]);
```